# Regex rule to match % sign in url for apache mod rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Hello my rewrite rule is failling sometimes because my urls have % signs in them.

For example this url:

```
http://www.chillisource.co.uk/product/Grocery/Dr.%20Burnoriums%20Psycho%20Juice/1/B005MSE5KG/Psycho_Juice_70%_Ghost_Pepper
```

This is my rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z]+)/([\sa-zA-Z0-9\-\+\.]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+) /product?&cat=$1&q=$2&page=$3&prod=$4&prodName=$5
```

How can I modify the 5th rule ([a-zA-Z0-9]+) to not fail on when there is a % in the product name ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you've tried "([a-zA-Z0-9\%]+)"?

Comment: @Truth You're right...I'd had the same thought, about 2 seconds after clicking the button.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, it's not `%20`, but space. That is, the URL passed to rewrite adter urldecoding. If not, then just add percent sign to the range. (if yes — space).

Answer (score 0):

---- Forget this part, I misunderstood the question ----

<s>From what I get from the mod_rewrite documentation (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), you should not have to deal with hex encoded characters (I assume that from the following statement:</s>

> THE_REQUEST
>       The full HTTP request line sent by the browser to the server (e.g., "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1"). This does not include any additional headers sent by the browser. **This value has not been unescaped (decoded), unlike most other variables below**.

In fact, using mod_rewrite would be practically impossible since you'd have to deal with that *EVERYWHERE*, e.g., you can always write %41 instead of 'A'.

--- But the following still is true ---

But your rewrite rule can't work, at least not with the request URL you posted: The last part of the regex "([a-zA-Z0-9]+)" is *FAR* too strict. In this case, it fails for the following reasons:

- It lacks a treatment of the percent sign, as in "70%"
- You forgot to include the underscore "_"

Try adding at least these two characters ("[a-zA-Z0-9%_]+") and it should work.

Comment: ("[a-zA-Z0-9%_]+") doesn't work either... :( how do I make my regex's less strict, is it possible to just let everthing through?